# Assign unique numeric values to distance strings (Spark)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a file full of strings ( its .nt file with URIs) and for simplicity I would like to change the string values to numeric values.

Two factors should be taken into consideration :
Generate a unique numeric value for each distinct string.
The ability to recover the original string from the generated number.

My intention is to convert the file to numeric values then perform a certain computation (which will be fast if the values are numeric) then reverse the outcome from numeric to strings.

I tried HashCode() but it dose not guarantee the uniqueness and its non reversible.

Is there any recommendation?
My code is run under Spark , Scala and Java.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use ZipWithIndex functionality of spark to create unique index.

> The challenge is to get back the string back from number, 
>   You have to save the string and zipIndex(or hold in memory) first,  so that
>   later you can join the output with this temp lookup table.

Comment: could you please clarify your point a little bit. I already tried ZipWithIndex but it does not give me a unique int

Comment: val days = Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")




days.zipWithIndex.foreach {
    case(day, count) => println(s"$count is $day")
}